# Cannot execute user defined function UDF in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am creating a function to return the full name of a customer when a customer id is entered:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION displayName
(
    @customer_id int
)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name varchar(50)
    SELECT @name = (SELECT name_first + ' ' + name_last AS FULL_NAME FROM DT_CUSTOMERS WHERE customer_id = @customer_id)
    RETURN @name
END
GO
```

Is something wrong with my code? How do I run it?

Comment: 1. how do you use the function? functions can be used as part of the SELECT clause of a query, e.g. `SELECT dbo.displayName(42)`
2. if you concatenate NULL with string, the result is NULL, so if either `first_name` or `last_name` are null, the result is NULL.

Comment: I always get this error

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'displayName' is not a recognized built-in function name.


i've created many versions with different names

Comment: Show the code you use to execute function?

Answer (score 1):

Common practice is to define in which DB you are going to run the query (you might be in the wrong db where you don't have any rights?) and which schema you want to add to it:
When executed like this, it should work.

```
USE
databasename_here
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.displayName
(
    @customer_id int
)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name varchar(50)
    SELECT @name = (SELECT name_first + ' ' + name_last AS FULL_NAME FROM DT_CUSTOMERS WHERE customer_id = @customer_id)
    RETURN @name
END
GO
```

It should be executed as follows:

```
SELECT 
   dbo.displayName(column_which_contains_id) 
from db.schema.table
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work in my case without the user.

I had to type dbo.displayName